# Define a linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\mathrm{Im}(f) = \{ x-y+z=0 \}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Well, this is an easy question as, from the definition of $\mathrm{Im}(f)$, one can quickly infer that $z=-x-y$; thus there are two degree of freedom and:
\begin{equation}
f(x,y,z)=(x,y,-x-y) \Leftrightarrow f(x,y,z)=(-x,-y,x+y).
\end{equation}
Nevertheless I cannot explain well the procedure to get the result. Can anyone help me, please? Thank you all.

Comment: A linear map in a finite dimensional vector space is implemented with a matrix. Can you find a matrix which does your transformation?

Comment: What might help you to better understand what's happening is to find ALL linear maps having requested properties.

Answer (score 1):

Your biconditional does not make a lot of sense: It is not true that if $f(x, y, z) = (x, y, -x-y)$, then $f(x, y, z) = (-x, -y, x+ y)$.

That being said, your approach is a good one: You come up with a good guess at what such an $f$ should be; namely that $f(x, y, z) = (x, y, -x-y)$ is a candidate for a function satisfying the desired criterion. As it turns out though, this function won't quite do the job: $f(1, 1, 1) = (1, 1, -2)$ is not in $\{x-y+z = 0\}$ since $1-1-2 \not= 0$. What *should* be true though, is that $z = y - x$, so let us instead try with $f(x, y, z) = (x, y, y-x)$.

So, to see that this one satisfies the criterion, let $(x, y, z) \in \mathrm{Im}(f)$. That is, there exists $(x', y', z')$ so that $(x, y, z) = f(x', y', z') = (x', y', y'-x')$. It follows that $x = x'$, $y = y'$, and $z = y'-x' = y-x$. In particular, $x - y + z = x - y + y - x = 0$, so $(x, y, z) \in \{x - y + z = 0\}$.

Now, this only shows that $\mathrm{Im}(f) \subseteq \{x-y+z=0\}$. To see that $\{x-y+z=0\} \subseteq \mathrm{Im}(f)$, let $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be given with $x-y+z = 0$. We now need to find some $(x', y', z')$ so that $f(x', y', z') = (x, y, z)$. Inspired by the above, we let $x' = x$, $y' = y$ and take $z'$ to be anything. Then $f(x', y', z') = f(x, y, z') = (x, y, y-x)$. Now, $z = y-x$, so $(x, y, y-x) = (x, y, z)$, and so $(x, y, z) \in \mathrm{Im}(f)$.